# NullReference on object in code behind after AsyncPostBack using UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel, nullreferenceexception

I'm building a simple game in an ASP.NET/VB.NET web app.  The game has a UI made up of several ImageButtons.

The web page's code behind file holds an instance to the **game** object which will manage each turn taken by players.

Everything worked when the Game object's methods were Shared.

**The problem** occurred after refactoring to make the game object work as an instance instead of a shared class.  Now, when the action returns to the code behind, the instance of the game object is *nothing*.

I suspect that this has something to do with view state, but uh... Google hasn't helped.

**The code bits:**

```
Public Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Private _gamePanel As Panel
        Private _updatePanel as UpdatePanel
        Private _game as Game

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

                'create a new instance of the game object on first loading page
                _game = New Game(width, height, cellsToWin)

            End If

            ' DisplayGameBoard() does the following:
            '  * Add images to the GameBoard panel inside of the GameBoardUpdatePanel
            '  * Attach click event handler to each image (addressOf located in this 
            '      code behind file
            '  * DisplayGameBoard() works fine the first time but fails on
            '      subsequent post backs because there is no game object instance
            Me.DisplayGameBoard()

        End Sub
```

(From the page directive)

```
Language="vb" 
AutoEventWireup="false" 
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="Game._Default" 
ValidateRequest="false" 
EnableEventValidation="false"
EnableViewState="true"
```

(update panel on the web page)

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="GameBoardUpdatePanel" 
                     runat="server" 
                     UpdateMode="Conditional" 
                     RenderMode="Block" 
                     EnableViewState="true"
                     ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
                     ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="PlayerName"
                        runat="server"></asp:Label>

            <asp:Panel ID="GameBoard"
                        runat="server"
                        cssclass="gameBoard"></asp:Panel>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not ViewState, it's simply the life time of the `_Default` instance.

You create an instance of the `Game` class and store that as a member of the page, and expect that instance to survive. The problem is that the instance of the page doesn't survive.

Each request for the page will result in a new instance of the `_Default` class to be created, and when the response is created the instance is thrown away. The reference to the instance of the `Game` class that you have stored in the page is also thrown away, and you lose any way to access it.

If you want to keep the instance of the `Game` class, you can store it in the `Session` collection, which is user specific:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

  'create a new instance of the game object on first loading page
  _game = New Game(width, height, cellsToWin)
  ' store the reference in the user session
  Session("game") = _game

Else

  ' get the reference back from the user session
  _game = DirectCast(Session("game"), Game)

End If
```

However, you should be carful about how much you store in the user session. Normally objects that are created in a page are short lived (i.e. milliseconds), so they have a small impact on the server resources. Anything that you store in the user session will be extremely long lived in comparison. Consider how large the `Game` object is, and if you really need to keep the entire object, or if you can keep just the information needed to recreate it for each request.